# React How do I create a Multiple App Website

Tags: reactjs, react-router

First of, let me apologise for the following question. I'm sure this must be a common use case, but I probably don't know enough to know where to look, or even to know the right question. I am new to react.

I am building a website which should have two 'ReactDOM.render(...)' applications injected into it:

`example.com/`

this is the normal react entry point (App.js). It will show pages which describe the what the site is, about, the contact page, etc, and a Sign In page.

`example.com/signedin`

Once the user has signed in, they will be redirected to the `https://www.example.com/signedin` page. Anything below the `signedin` URL should be part of a different react app (i.e. a second ReactDOM.render(...) root component load), as this will be the content that only a signed in user can access. The size of the `signedin` app will be significantly large so I want to componentize that part of the system separately from the main publicly accessible parts.

The problem I'm having is I can not find any way to do this. Maybe I'm doing this wrong or asking the wrong questions of google.

What I have looked into so far, is using `Router` in App and then creating a another similar component call `SignedInApp.js` and I've tried to load the relevant component. But this doesn't seem to work, and I'm going down a rabbit hole.

I've looked at mutiple HTML pages, but the tutorials that I have seen talk about serving HTML pages and not about the `ReactDOM.render(...)` type of stuff within those different pages.

Like I say, I'm probably not asking the right question, so if anybody can point me into the right direction or give me some pointers, I'll give you a massive up vote and be forever grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Having two `ReactDOM.render(...)` to inject React code is not a suggested method and it might make your codebase more confusing.
If the sole reason for you to have two `ReactDOM.render(...)` is to manage the bundle size, you should strongly consider [React code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#code-splitting).

I would suggest using the [React Lazy Load](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) to split the code at the route level and load such authentication needing components(pages) like "AppDashboard" or
"Settings" with React Lazy Load.

The official React example on how to use this is as follows -

```js
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <OtherComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You should also note down that you would need to use it inside React Suspense (React lazy and Suspense are not yet available for server-side rendering). According to the official docs -

> The lazy component should then be rendered inside a Suspense
> component, which allows us to show some fallback content (such as a
> loading indicator) while we’re waiting for the lazy component to load.